# Is a mapping an action?

Tags: set-theory

In many contexts we have the concept of mapping one element to another. Is the mapping itself an object which has a lifecycle? What makes the mapping come into existence?

I may not be asking this very articulately but when it is stated that there is a mapping, what causes this? Where is the information that says the mapping exists stored?

Is this related perhaps to Axiom of Choice?

Comment: A maping is a set of ordered pairs, its existence comes from the Axioms of Set Theory, particularly the replacement axiom- which gives the result that if A and B are sets, the cross product A × B, is also a set. Then, by the Subset Axiom ( Axiom of Separation), as a function is a subset of the cross product, we get that the function exists. The Axiom of Choice is another axiom, which allows us to say that particular function exists- to be specific the Axiom of Choice gives us the existence the aptly named- Choice Function.

Comment: Another way, to show the existence of certain functions, is by the Recursion Theorems, which are statements about, if we can define a algorithm using recursion, we can construct a recursive function, which by the recursion theorem- we are guranteed that it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mathematics, we generally don't assign lifecycles to the objects we talk about.  Most of mathematics will assume every object under discussion is a set, and these sets are presumed to simply exist or not exist, for all time. We use axioms to determine that certain sets must exist or not exist, though generally speaking our axioms cannot answer every question about existence of sets.  This applies to mappings in particular - there are certain axioms (including the "axiom of choice") that assert the existence of mappings satisfying certain properties.

To be precise, a mapping (also called a "function") from $A\to B$ is just a subset $\Gamma$ of the cartesian product $A\times B$ satisfying a certain requirement (namely, the so-called "vertical line test" saying that for each $a\in A$ there is exactly one $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in \Gamma$.)

In other words, we formally define a function to be equal to its graph, even though informally we might be tempted to think of it as a rule giving a procedure to produce something.

Formally speaking a mapping (or more generally any set) is just an abstraction, so nothing is being stored here.

Since you talked about lifecycle and storing information you might be coming from computer science, and if so I will just mention as an aside that mathematical functions are distinct from those in computer science, as mathematical functions, roughly speaking, always return a single unique value, and have no side-effects.  You may wish to explore [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), a paradigm that treats functions in computer science more like their mathematical counterparts.